# Rails Fabrication gem association creating many objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, fabrication-gem

I have two models with a simple `has_many` association

```
class Usuario < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :publicaciones, dependent: :destroy
end

class Publicacion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :usuario, dependent: :destroy
  validates_presence_of :usuario
end
```

And these are the fabricators

```
Fabricator(:usuario_con_10_publicaciones) do
  nombre { FFaker::NameMX.name }
  publicaciones(count: 10)
end

Fabricator(:publicacion) do
  texto { FFaker::Lorem.paragraphs }
  usuario
end
```

When I use the second one it works fine, it creates **one** `Publicacion` and **one** `Usuario`

```
> a = Fabricate :publicacion
> Usuario.count
=> 1
> Publicacion.count
=> 1
```

But when I use the first one, it creates **ten** `Publicaciones` but **eleven** `Usuarios`, with all the `Publicaciones` associated just with the last one.

```
> u = Fabricate :usuario_con_10_publicaciones
> Usuario.count
=> 11
> Publicacion.count
=> 10
```

Shouldn't it create just **one** `Usuario` and **ten** `Publicaciones`?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steve is right about what's going on. Another solution is to suppress the creation of the `usario` in the `publicaciones`.

```
Fabricator(:usuario_con_10_publicaciones) do
  nombre { FFaker::NameMX.name }
  publicaciones(count: 10) { Fabricate.build(:publicacion, usuario: nil) }
end
```

ActiveRecord will properly associate them for you when the tree is persisted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you create the `usario` it creates 10 `publicaciones` *but* every `publicaciones` fabrication creates one `usario`

You can use transients to suppress  the default creation of the new `usario` records.

```
Fabricator(:usuario_con_10_publicaciones) do
  nombre { FFaker::NameMX.name }
  publicaciones(count: 10) { Fabricate(:publicacion, no_usario: true) }
end

Fabricator(:publicacion) do
  transient :no_usario
  texto { FFaker::Lorem.paragraphs }
  usuario { |attrs| Fabricate(:usario) unless attrs[:no_usario] }
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, using transients is a good idea, the problem with your suggestion is that it is not valid to create a `Publicacion` without an `Usuario`. This is solved using `Fabricate.build` instead, as shown in the answer of Paul Elliott.